# \bf cause part of equation undisplayed

Tags: equations, bold, vector, displaybreak

### background

I want to show a multi-normal distribution, thus $x$ should be a vector. So I decide to use `\bf` or `\mathbf`to bold it on **overleaf**. However, when I bold my `x`， the `\Sigma` is **undisplayed**. I don't know why, maybe it is due to my loading packages or the example environment? I provide MWE below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[]{CJK}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{(\oldref{#1})}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\log{\frac{g(\bf{x})}{f(\bf{x})}} =& \frac{1}{2}\log{\frac{|\Sigma_1|}{|\Sigma_2|}} + 
\frac{1}{2}(\mu_1^T \Sigma_1^{-1}\mu_1 - \mu_2^T \Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2) \\
&+ (\mu_2^{T}\Sigma_2^{-1} - \mu_1^{T}\Sigma_1^{-1})\bf{x} +
\frac{1}{2}\bf{x}^{T}(\Sigma_1^{-1} - \Sigma_2^{-1})\bf{x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Which shows:
[image]

If I do not `\bf{x}`, the code is like this:

```
\begin{example}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\log{\frac{g(\bf{x})}{f(\bf{x})}} =& \frac{1}{2}\log{\frac{|\Sigma_1|}{|\Sigma_2|}} + 
\frac{1}{2}(\mu_1^T \Sigma_1^{-1}\mu_1 - \mu_2^T \Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2) \\
&+ (\mu_2^{T}\Sigma_2^{-1} - \mu_1^{T}\Sigma_1^{-1})x + \frac{1}{2}x^{T}(\Sigma_1^{-1} - \Sigma_2^{-1})x
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{example}
```

Then, the display is right like this:
[image]

Comment: `\bf` is very different from `\mathbf` (say) in that it does not take an argument. It is also wrong in an equation. So use `\mathbf{x}` or `\boldsymbol{x}` but not `\bf`. If you want to confine the effects of `\bf` to `x`, use `{\bf x}`, but, as I said, you should not use it at all.

Comment: `\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{(\oldref{#1})}` is another stunt that is really not to be used. There is the beautiful command `\eqref` for that, and clever users use the `cleveref`` package with `\cref`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you so much! Change all `\bf` to `\mathbf` works very well. And your clever `ref` advise works too!

Comment: `\bf`, along with most legacy two-letter font selection commands, has been deprecated for 25 years. Where did you find `\bf{x}` recommended to get a boldface letter in math? The bin is waiting for that guide.

Comment: Not from document, my senior classmate told me to use `\bf`....   @egreg

Comment: @Travis That could be a reason for breaking a friendship. `;-)` That, however, brings in the question: where did your classmate learn it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the release of LaTeX2ε in **June 1994**,* the commands

```
\bf  \it  \sl  \rm
```

have been deprecated. The LaTeX kernel doesn't define them; however, document classes *may* define them (and indeed, the standard classes do, for backward compatibility reasons).

The fact that `\bf` seems to work in your document is not a reason for using it.

Besides, the pre-1994 older manuals told one to say `{\bf x}` in order to get a boldface letter in math. Newer manuals tell you to use `\mathbf{x}`.

If you do `\usepackage{bm}` (after loading `amsmath`), you have the alternative of using `\bm{x}` that you may like more for your vectors.

***Never ever use `\bf` again and remove it from all your documents.***

---

As far as your code is concerned, if I compile your code with TeX Live 2018, I get

[image]

The Sigmas you don't see are there, but they're boldface, which I don't think you want. There's much more unwanted boldface, too.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[fontset=windows]{ctex}
\usepackage[]{CJK}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{break}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%
  {\newline}{}%
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\let\oldref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{(\oldref{#1})}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
\begin{multline}
\log{\frac{g(\mathbf{x})}{f(\mathbf{x})}} = \frac{1}{2}\log{\frac{|\Sigma_1|}{|\Sigma_2|}} + 
\frac{1}{2}(\mu_1^T \Sigma_1^{-1}\mu_1 - \mu_2^T \Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2) \\
+ (\mu_2^{T}\Sigma_2^{-1} - \mu_1^{T}\Sigma_1^{-1})\mathbf{x} +
\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{T}(\Sigma_1^{-1} - \Sigma_2^{-1})\mathbf{x}
\end{multline}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Footnote**

* Yes, that's more than a quarter of a century, at the date of writing.